# Bash - joining (merging) files by columns

Tags: linux, bash, file, join, awk

There are three files with columns, delimiter is "|", columns in lines might be empty. I need to join second and third files to first using columns 3 and 4 in first file, and column 1 in second and third.

For example:

file1.txt:

```
123456||4|11|17|A||10|B|1
123457||4|11|17|A||12||1
123458||5|11|17|A||1|Б|1
123459||6|13|17|A||1|Б|1
```

file2.txt:

```
4|Forth
5|Fifth
6|Sixth
```

file3.txt:

```
11|st.|Eleventh
13|pr.|Thirteenth
```

What output I desire:

```
123456||4|Forth|11|st.|Eleventh|17|A||10|B|1
123457||4|Forth|11|st.|Eleventh|17|A||12||1
123458||5|Fifth|11|st.|Eleventh|17|A||1|Б|1
123459||6|Sixth|13|pr.|Thirteenth|17|A||1|Б|1
```

How to write Bash script that will do what I need? I understand that it's awt command, but I couldn't write the script. Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }
     NR == FNR {a[$1]=$0; next}
     NR == FNR + length(a) {b[$1]=$0; next}
     {$3=b[$3]; $4=a[$4]} 1' file3.txt file2.txt file1.txt
123456||4|Forth|11|st.|Eleventh|17|A||10|B|1
123457||4|Forth|11|st.|Eleventh|17|A||12||1
123458||5|Fifth|11|st.|Eleventh|17|A||1|Б|1
123459||6|Sixth|13|pr.|Thirteenth|17|A||1|Б|1
```

**Explanation:**

- `BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }` - Set input and output field separators as pipe `|`
- `NR == FNR` - Execute this block for first file only
- `a[$1]=$0; next` - Create an array `a` with key as `$1` and value as complete line
- `NR == FNR + length(a)` - Execute this block for second file only
- `b[$1]=$0; next` - Create an array `b` with key as `$1` and value as complete line
- Execute next block `{...}` for the last (3rd) file
- `$3=b[$3];` - Assign value of `b[$3]` to 3rd field
- `$4=a[$4];` - Assign value of `a[$4]` to 4th field
- `1` - Is the default action to print each record

Comment: Well @anubhava I'm becoming fan of yours, this answer is a great answer, exactly looks like SQL join operation. I'm learning lots from your answers.

Comment: Thanks for kind words @Skynet. Yes it is indeed 3 way SQL join operation. Initially I wasn't sure how to do it but once I started building it things became clear. And yes that `NR == FNR + length(a)` trick came handy :)

Comment: yeah and it's also give good explanations, if anytime I need to do this I will definitely like to follow your answer :)

Comment: You said: 1 - Is the default action to print each record , how can I write the result into the new file?

Comment: You can just redirect output using standard > outfile redirection or use print $0 > "out file" in ask.

Comment: @anubhava oh, there's new problem, how to set output field separator = ";"? I did OFS=";" but it didn't work for all of the fields

Comment: Change `BEGIN` block to `BEGIN{ FS="|"; OFS=";" }`

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried, but I got this:
`123456;;4|Forth;11|st.|Evelenth;17;A;;10;Б;1`

Comment: I think I can change file delimiters before awt call, but maybe there's another solution with just awt command?

Comment: It is because your other files still are pipe delimited. If you want `;` then better replace pipe with `;` in other 2 files also. btw you could also do: `gsub(/[|]/, ";");` to replace `|` by `;`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the files are sorted:

```
join -t'|' -1 4 -2 1 \
     <(join -t '|' -1 3 -2 1 file1.txt file2.txt) file3.txt
```

If you really need the fields in a specific order add a output format option:

```
 -o1.2,1.3,1.1,1.11,1.4,2.2,2.3,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,1.10,1.11
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='|' read c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10
        do
        st1=$( fgrep "$c3" file2.txt )
        st2=$( fgrep "$c4" file3.txt )
        echo "$c1|$c2|$st1|$st2|$c5|$c6|$c7|$c8|$c9|$c10"
        done
```